# Plotting multiple columns in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have these data:

```
-22.42778  20.55840  -4.3E+0015
-22.41731  20.58783  -4.3E+0015
-22.40206  20.59463  -4.3E+0015
-22.39814  20.57130  -4.3E+0015
-22.39906  20.53965  -4.3E+0015
-22.39983  20.50836  -4.3E+0015
-22.40005  20.47765  -4.3E+0015
-22.40005  20.44699  -4.3E+0015
-22.40008  20.41630  -4.3E+0015
-22.40027  20.38591  -4.3E+0015
-22.40069  20.35632  -4.3E+0015
-22.40138  20.32813  -4.3E+0015
-22.40240  20.30202  -4.3E+0015
-22.40383  20.27882  -4.3E+0015
-22.40579  20.25964  -4.3E+0015
-22.40820  20.24600  -4.3E+0015
-22.40945  20.23944  -4.3E+0015
-22.40346  20.23741  -4.3E+0015
-22.39212  20.22206  -4.3E+0015
-22.39124  20.18338  -4.3E+0015
-22.39515  20.14256  -4.3E+0015
-22.39857  20.10868  -4.3E+0015
-22.40100  20.08127  -4.2E+0015
-22.40275  20.05874  -4.2E+0015
-22.40409  20.03998  -4.2E+0015
-22.40522  20.02431  -4.2E+0015
-22.40623  20.01140  -4.2E+0015
-22.40724  20.00111  -4.2E+0015
-22.40834  19.99357  -4.2E+0015
-22.40966  19.98914  -4.2E+0015
-22.41132  19.98856  -4.2E+0015
-22.41328  19.99309  -4.2E+0015
-22.41413  20.00416  -4.2E+0015
-22.40840  20.01972  -4.2E+0015
-22.39701  20.02296  -4.2E+0015
-22.39569  20.00142  -4.2E+0015
-22.39942  19.97571  -4.2E+0015
-22.40266  19.95608  -4.2E+0015
-22.40487  19.94234  -4.2E+0015
-22.40639  19.93292  -4.2E+0015
-22.40752  19.92668  -4.2E+0015
-22.40844  19.92297  -4.2E+0015
-22.40927  19.92146  -4.2E+0015
-22.41011  19.92204  -4.2E+0015
-22.41104  19.92484  -4.2E+0015
-22.41218  19.93024  -4.2E+0015
-22.41363  19.93899  -4.2E+0015
-22.41530  19.95233  -4.2E+0015
-22.41589  19.97177  -4.2E+0015
-22.41031  19.99581  -4.2E+0015
-22.39881  20.00894  -4.2E+0015
-22.39726  19.99643  -4.2E+0015
-22.40121  19.97802  -4.2E+0015
-22.40464  19.96521  -4.2E+0015
-22.40694  19.95815  -4.2E+0015
-22.40851  19.95528  -4.2E+0015
-22.40967  19.95545  -4.2E+0015
-22.41062  19.95798  -4.2E+0015
-22.41147  19.96253  -4.2E+0015
-22.41233  19.96900  -4.2E+0015
-22.41329  19.97752  -4.2E+0015
-22.41444  19.98845  -4.2E+0015
-22.41588  20.00253  -4.2E+0015
-22.41750  20.02096  -4.2E+0015
-22.41801  20.04528  -4.2E+0015
-22.41250  20.07453  -4.2E+0015
-22.40065  20.09448  -4.2E+0015
-22.39874  20.08842  -4.2E+0015
-22.40303  20.07478  -4.2E+0015
-22.40679  20.06640  -4.2E+0015
-22.40931  20.06381  -4.2E+0015
-22.41103  20.06544  -4.2E+0015
-22.41231  20.07012  -4.2E+0015
-22.41335  20.07714  -4.2E+0015
-22.41430  20.08616  -4.3E+0015
-22.41526  20.09706  -4.3E+0015
-22.41631  20.10996  -4.3E+0015
-22.41755  20.12521  -4.3E+0015
-22.41909  20.14351  -4.3E+0015
-22.42079  20.16604  -4.3E+0015
-22.42139  20.19436  -4.3E+0015
-22.41603  20.22793  -4.3E+0015
-22.40359  20.25389  -4.3E+0015
-22.40102  20.25385  -4.3E+0015
-22.40562  20.24457  -4.3E+0015
-22.40979  20.24022  -4.3E+0015
-22.41262  20.24178  -4.3E+0015
-22.41456  20.24770  -4.3E+0015
-22.41602  20.25678  -4.3E+0015
-22.41723  20.26829  -4.3E+0015
-22.41833  20.28187  -4.3E+0015
-22.41945  20.29740  -4.3E+0015
-22.42067  20.31498  -4.3E+0015
-22.42210  20.33495  -4.3E+0015
-22.42383  20.35801  -4.3E+0015
-22.42578  20.38530  -4.3E+0015
-22.42671  20.41838  -4.3E+0015
-22.42175  20.45713  -4.3E+0015
-22.40877  20.48999  -4.3E+0015
-22.40528  20.49729  -4.3E+0015
-22.41015  20.49379  -4.3E+0015
-22.41483  20.49501  -4.3E+0015
-22.41809  20.50243  -4.3E+0015
-22.42040  20.51457  -4.3E+0015
-22.42219  20.53018  -4.3E+0015
-22.42371  20.54854  -4.3E+0015
-22.42514  20.56930  -4.3E+0015
-22.42658  20.59234  -4.3E+0015
-22.42815  20.61778  -4.3E+0015
-22.42995  20.64598  -4.3E+0015
-22.43208  20.67763  -4.3E+0015
-22.43449  20.71386  -4.3E+0015
-22.43603  20.75627  -4.3E+0015
-22.43183  20.80506  -4.3E+0015
-22.41861  20.84995  -4.3E+0015
-22.41415  20.87034  -4.3E+0015
-22.41925  20.87873  -4.3E+0015
-22.42448  20.89185  -4.3E+0015
-22.42817  20.91164  -4.3E+0015
-22.43074  20.93653  -4.3E+0015
-22.43263  20.96507  -4.3E+0015
-22.43408  20.99622  -4.3E+0015
-22.43522  21.02925  -4.3E+0015
-22.43615  21.06353  -4.3E+0015
-22.43694  21.09859  -4.4E+0015
-22.43768  21.13408  -4.4E+0015
-22.43850  21.16990  -4.4E+0015
-22.43939  21.20643  -4.4E+0015
-22.43940  21.24462  -4.4E+0015
-22.43388  21.28451  -4.4E+0015
-22.41856  21.31680  -4.4E+0015
-22.41110  21.32044  -4.4E+0015
-22.41468  21.30590  -4.4E+0015
-22.41913  21.29163  -4.4E+0015
-22.42233  21.28092  -4.4E+0015
-22.42468  21.27306  -4.4E+0015
-22.42662  21.26735  -4.4E+0015
-22.42840  21.26352  -4.4E+0015
-22.43018  21.26158  -4.4E+0015
-22.43203  21.26168  -4.4E+0015
-22.43405  21.26411  -4.4E+0015
-22.43633  21.26930  -4.4E+0015
-22.43899  21.27793  -4.4E+0015
-22.44202  21.29110  -4.4E+0015
-22.44448  21.31031  -4.4E+0015
-22.44165  21.33621  -4.4E+0015
-22.42793  21.36071  -4.4E+0015
-22.42059  21.36229  -4.4E+0015
-22.42536  21.34847  -4.4E+0015
```

and i need plot like this graph

[image: graph]

Simply i need use all 3 columns. I start like

```
plot "data.txt" using 1,\
     "data.txt" using 2,\
     "data.txt" using 3
```

But it doesn't work as i want. My result was really bad as this sample shows

[image: myplot]

I never work with any plotting system, but i need it for my graduate. If you can help me i will be so happy.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first plot was not made with the data you gave. On that
plot, the points are approximately between 50 and 80 on the vertical
axis. In the data file, none of the points are in that range.

Still, maybe this script can get you started.

```
# Horizontal grid lines only.
set grid y linetype 1 linecolor 0 linewidth -0.5

# Plots with lines instead of points.
set style data lines

# Legend below the plot.
set key outside bottom center horizontal

# Extend the range of the axis a little so the data points don't end up
# on the edge of the plot.
set offsets graph 0.1, graph 0.1, graph 0.1, graph 0.1

# Remove the border around the plot.
unset border

# No tick marks on the right and top.
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror

set title 'Chart Title'

# Make the lines thicker by setting lw (short for linewidth) larger than 1.
plot 'data.txt' using 1 lw 3 title 'Potenciální',\
     'data.txt' using 2 lw 3 title 'Kinetická',\
     'data.txt' using 3 lw 3 title 'Celková'
```

[image]